# Cannot use table 'Accounts' for entity type 'User' since it is being used for entity type 'Address'

Tags: entity-relationship, navigation-properties, ef-core-2.2

I am losing my mind right now. I am trying to model my database model with navigation properties that exist on both child and parent identities. Meaning, the parent has a nav property pointing to the child and the child has a nav property pointing to the parent.

Here is my Model:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public User Account { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<User> Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

I then created a database context class like so:

```
public class UserManagementDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    public UserManagementDbContext(DbContextOptions<UserManagementDbContext> options)
           : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<User>()
            .OwnsOne(cu => cu.Employee)
            .HasOne(e => e.Account);
        builder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne(cu => cu.Company)
            .WithMany(c => c.Accounts);
        builder.Entity<Employee>()
            .OwnsOne(e => e.Address)
            .HasOne(a => a.Employee);

        builder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Accounts");
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
    }
}
```

I then call EnsureCreated() method of database in my Startup.cs like so:

```
private async Task InitializeDatabase(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    using (var serviceScope = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        using (var db = serviceProvider.GetService<UserManagementDbContext>())
        {
            db.Database.EnsureCreated();
            //...omitted
        }
    }
}
```

This is where the app fails with the above error and I do not understand why. There is no relationship between the Accounts and Addresses tables. Either I am blind as a bat and didn't notice a typo or this error is really confusing.

Can anyone help me out here?

EDIT: Please note that I do not want to use foreign keys, only navigation properties.

Comment: `OwnsOne` is not for normal entities and relationships. Looks like you need `HasOne` + `WithOne`.

Comment: When I do it with `HasOne`, I get a different error `The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship between 'Address.Employee' and 'Employee.Address'` The way I do it above is the result of searching for the solution of that error.

Comment: The only way I got it working is to remove the nav properties from the child entities. But that removes the convenience of being able to use them in code.

Comment: It can be resolved, but the solution depends on whether you want to use shared PK association or separate FK , i.e. in `Employee`  **table** do you want separate `AccountID` FK or using PK `ID` as FK is fine (this is the default option for one-to-one relationships). Once you decide that, it's a matter of something like `builder.Entity<User>().HasOne(e => e.Employee).WithOne(e => e.Account).HasForeignKey<Employee>("AccountID").IsRequired();`. Similar for `Employee -> Address`.

Comment: I don't really understand, sorry. My `User` class is the primary entity, the `Employee` class is the child. Do you mean I can just tell EF that my `Employee` class should point to the `User` class' PK property as it's foreign key?

Comment: See the documentation for [one-to-one relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#one-to-one)

Comment: Kinda disappointing, also due to the fact that many to many are not supported without a join table. Oh well. Guess I have to use FK.